# Dir /b with "/" as last character when a folder

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, dir

I use

```
dir /b   > test.txt
```

in order to get a list of all files and folders in my current directory.

Is there a way to have :

- normal filename if it is a file, example `blabla.txt`
- "/" at the end if it is a folder, example `myfolder\`

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to do it in two steps. One command for folders with appended `\`, and another command for files.

```
for /d %F in (*) do @(echo %F\)>test.txt
for %F in (*) do @(echo %F)>>test.txt
```

Double up the percents if used in a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
:: method 1
SETLOCAL
ECHO %TIME%
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b') DO (
 ECHO %%~ai|FIND "d" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO(%%i) ELSE (ECHO(%%i\)
)
)>u:\file1.txt
endlocal
ECHO %TIME%

:: method 2
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b') DO (
 SET notdir=%%~ai
 if "!notdir:~0,1!"=="d" (ECHO(%%i\) ELSE (ECHO(%%i)
)
)>U:\file2.txt
endlocal
ECHO %TIME%

:: method 3
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b') DO (
 SET notdir=%%~ai&CALL :isitadir
 if DEFINED notdir (ECHO(%%i) ELSE (ECHO(%%i\)
)
)>U:\file3.txt
endlocal
ECHO %TIME%
FC u:\file1.txt u:\file2.txt
FC u:\file1.txt u:\file3.txt
GOTO :eof

:isitadir
IF %notdir:~0,1%==d SET "notdir="
GOTO :eof
```

Three methods shown.

The first is quite slow - took about 35 seconds to run on my test directory with 1976 files and 333 directories.

The second took under a second, but doesn't correctly process names containing `!`

The third is more complex, but produced the same result as the first in about 6 sec.

Answer (score 1):

This does as you ask.  Folders have \ at the end, files don't.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b') do (
   if exist "%%a\" (
      echo %%a\
   ) else (
      echo %%a
   )
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

To list files that end with "txt"

```
dir /b *.txt > test.txt
```

List only directories:

```
dir /ad /b
```